# java, calling a method after a modifiable delay

Tags: java, android, methods, execution, schedule

I'd like to ask you about the best solution/idea how to solve a following situation. 
I'm developing an Android app which on one of screens has a set of buttons. After clicking on any of them a kind of config is posted to the server over http. 
To prevent multiple clicks one by one which could result in concurrency problems I decided that after each click on a particular button there'll be a waiting interval of 30 seconds before a config is sent to the server. If another click on the same button happens before this 30 seconds are exceeded, then the execution of method is delayed for another 30 seconds - as long as no new click is performed, then the config will be sent.

I need an idea of an algorithm which would implement the mechanism above. What I know is that I don't want to start a separate thread for each click (too heavy for my app). A potential idea is to make a queue of events and send them in a loop but idea of a running endless loop in a thread (or Handler) also isn't my favourite.

Maybe there's a kind of mechanism in Android or J2SE in general, that allows to schedule an execution of method to a given time in the future *but* still be able to postopone execution for some additional time before 30sec rolled out.

thanks in advance!

Comment: **"To prevent multiple clicks..."** - The simplest way to do that is to simply disable the buttons after one has been clicked. Once the required action has been performed enable them again.

Comment: J2SE !?  are you really using Java 2?